# Why is my generator not yielding the argument value passed in from the next method?

Tags: javascript, function, iterator, generator

I am reading the documentation on generator functions on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) to learn redux-saga. Here they mention that you can pass in arguments to the iterator.next() method as shown below in this example featuring on the website.

```
function* logGenerator() {
  console.log(0);
  console.log(1, yield);
  console.log(2, yield);
  console.log(3, yield);
}

var gen = logGenerator();

// the first call of next executes from the start of the function
// until the first yield statement
gen.next();             // 0
gen.next('pretzel');    // 1 pretzel
gen.next('california'); // 2 california
gen.next('mayonnaise'); // 3 mayonnaise
```

This works as expected.

---

Now I am trying to play around with it and have written this generator.

```js
function* foo() {
    yield '1';
    console.log(yield);
    yield '3';
    return '4';
}

var result = foo();
console.log(result.next());
console.log(result.next(2));
console.log(result.next());
console.log(result.next());
```

The output i am expecting is **1 2 3 4** but i am getting **1,undefined,undefined,3,4**. What is the problem ?

**EDIT**: As pointed out in the comments, I didn't fully show the output properly. Please run the snippet. If i add the arguments to all the next() statements i get the following output.

```
{ value: '1', done: false }
{ value: undefined, done: false }
3
{ value: '3', done: false }
{ value: '4', done: true }
```

Comment: `i am getting 1,undefined,undefined,3,4` no you aren't ... look closely at what you are getting - I've made your code into a snippet that runs, and the output is not as simple as you say

Comment: also, try adding arguments to all the `result.next` to see what it happening in greater detail

Comment: You should be getting a bunch of objects. `console.log(result.next().value)`. `result.next(2)` really goes to `yield '3'`, passing the `2` to the yield.

Comment: I don't quite get it could you explain step by step ?

Comment: @HarshLimaye - it's tricky to follow until you get it! This article is good at explaining it: https://davidwalsh.name/es6-generators

Comment: "*The output i am expecting is 1 2 3 4*" - but you have 5 `console.log` statements!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generator functions use `yield` to yield at every `GeneratorObject.next()`. `yield` will even happen in a `console.log()`, so that should arguably throw a Syntax Error. When you use `GeneratorObject.next()` the first time, it yields and the Generator stops executing, so nothing below the `yield` runs. When you call `GeneratorObject.next(argument)` again, it is as if the argument is passed to the previous `yield`, for use only before the `yield`. See the following:

```js
function* gen_create(){ 
  let a = yield 1;
  console.log(a);
  let b = yield 2;
  console.log(b);
  let c = yield 3;
  console.log(c);
  return 4;
}
const gen = gen_create();
console.log(gen.next('cool').value);
// notice that 'cool' was not consoled
console.log(gen.next().value); // nothing was passed so it's undefined
console.log(gen.next('wow').value);
console.log(gen.next('last return works like yield').value);
```

Comment: You don't like my computing use of the word consoled? Sorry, I can't console you.

Comment: lol I still don't get it. According to me yield (something) is EQUAL to (something). I am thinking that when i call next(something) it will just go inside the body of the generator and execute the line where the next yield exists and replace it with the value that we have passed or the value next to it.

Comment: You'll just have to accept that it works the way it does. Personally, I wouldn't use Generator functions. Just use a class, and create methods to do what you want.